# Can I customize react-select Creatable to not show the create option?

Tags: react-select

I'm trying to customize react-select Creatable to hide the create menu option. I want the option to be created on enter or tab but not visible in the menu.

I'd be happy to add the option to 'Creatable' with a PR but I prefer to get some guidance first.

Comment: Could you describe a bit more the feature itself? Like an example of usage? When would the option be accessible or displayed etc?

Comment: I ended up with overriding the Option with something like this:
  
`const {hideCreatedOption} = selectProps;
  if (hideCreatedOption && __isNew__) {
    return null;
  }`

Comment: You should put it in a proper answer for other users :)